# Strapi Image Folders

Tags: strapi

I tried to find some plugin for supporting folders in strapi media library, but I found nothing. Do you know some projects, which have some custom media folders in strapi media library, like in google drive or other storages?

Answer (score 0):

https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/plugins/upload.html#upload-files

You can use AWS S3 plugin for strapi. It allows to set file paths. Standard media plugin of strapi doesn't support filepaths.

Answer (score 0):

Media Folder are set to be released in the [next version of Strapi.](https://feedback.strapi.io/customization/p/media-folders)

A temporary "fix" to organise your files is to use the S3 plugin as Gorav Singal mentions. If you set the filename to `a/b/file.jpg`, then the file will reside in subfolder b of a in S3, but it will still show all files in Strapi until next version.